# Default export not working for function if package.json exists - why?

Tags: typescript, import, export

I have the following file structure in vscode:

[image]

The files are:

./src/A/A.d.ts:

```
declare function a():void;
export default a;
```

./src/A/package.json:

```
{}
```

./src/B/B.d.ts:

```
declare function b(): void;
export default b;
```

and finally ./src/test.tsx

```
import a from "./A/A.js";
import { b } from "./B/B.js"; 

a(); // err: This expression is not callable. Type 'typeof import(".../src/A/A")' has no call signatures.
b(); // no err
```

with ./package.json

```
{
  "type": "module"
}
```

and ./tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./build",
        "target": "es2020",
        "module": "es2020",
        "lib": ["es2020","dom", "DOM.Iterable"] ,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "moduleResolution": "node16",
        "strict": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "composite":true,
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules"],
    "include": ["**/*.ts*"]
}
```

The default export of function a() causes an error in the main file test.tsx when imported and used. If I delete the empty ./src/A/package.json, everything is fine (as with the import and usage of function b() from B.d.ts. I cannot find any documentation in typescript describing or explaining this behavior. Any ideas anybody?

This is a simplification of a larger export / import issue I have with the [rc-tree](https://github.com/react-component/tree) module.